# Updating Apache on OS X

Tags: osx-lion, apache-http-server, benchmarking

When I run ApacheBench (which is included in Apache) on OS X Lion I [get a known](https://forrst.com/posts/Fixing_ApacheBench_bug_on_Mac_OS_X_Lion-wku) error.

```
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $> Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, zeustech.net/ Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, apache.org/
Benchmarking www..com (be patient)...Send request failed!
Send request failed!
Send request failed!
Send request failed!
apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (54)
Total of 4 requests completed
```

All solutions I can find are for earlier Apache versions, but not for Apache 2.4.2. The fixes I found don't work unfortunately.

How can I get the newest Apache version running?

Comment: You could just try compiling it from source – all the other self-contained installers only ship with outdated versions.